# Random tk window opens when trying to use a save dialogue from tk in pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Whenever I click the save button on my app, it opens a save dialogue that works correctly and a tkinter window that crashes as soon as I try to close it. Here is my code that somehow makes the random window:

```
import tkFileDialog,pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360))

pygame.display.set_caption("Idea Processor")

# code is cut here

try:
    ideasetupfonts = pygame.font.SysFont("Ubuntu", 36, False, False)
except:
    ideasetupfonts = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36, False, False)
# TextNameToBlit = ideasetupfonts.render(" TEXT HERE ",1,(0,0,0))

Potato = True
ShowToolbar = True
newSaveFile = {"Hello World":(50,50)}



def SaveFile():
    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**{"title":"Save Idea...","defaultextension":".txt","filetypes":[("text files", ".txt")],})
    if filename:
        saveFile = open(filename, 'w')
        print >>saveFile,newSaveFile
        saveFile.close()

while Potato:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Potato = False
    screen.fill(white)

    # and here

    mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # SaveFile button
    if mousex>=0 and mousex<=32 and mousey>=0 and mousey<=32 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (True, False, False) and ShowToolbar:
        SaveFile()


    # and here

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: the only window that popped up when i ran it was a pygame window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That window is the default Tk element that is created when a Tkinter widget is created if you haven't created a previous one. This happens because `tkFileDialog` is built on top of Tkinter. I suggest you to create that element yourself and hide it by calling its `withdraw` method.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, pygame

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

---

As a side note, I have seen that you have named the flag for your Pygame loop `Potato`. I don't know how it could be related with the real use of this variable, but I strongly recommend you to **use meaningful names** for your classes, variables and modules. Here it is [an article from Object Mentor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Naming.pdf) (which is part of the excellent book "Clean Code") exclusively about naming, I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Sorry, I have a strange habit of naming important variables "Potato". :P I'll change it soon.

Comment: @V360 "_I have a strange habit of naming important variables "Potato"_" I wish I could mark comments like this as favorites :)