# Better solution for random tk window opening that I didn't code for

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game using the Tkinter library and have completed my authentication feature mostly. However, I test my feature which opens an error window, and sure, the error window opens just fine, but then a titleless, blank window opens that I didn't at all code for. So I do the normal thing programmers do and see if anyone else has had the problem, and find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704506/random-tk-window-opens-when-trying-to-use-a-save-dialogue-from-tk-in-pygame). The answer is 8 years and 3 months old, and I imagine that it might be out of date, but I try to use the solution anyway. At first, it seems like it works, as when I put the username/passwords in wrong 3 times only the error message opens and not the random window. So I think I fixed it. But to my dismay, I discover that the hidden root window was somehow interfering with my code in a way that now, the window I try to open that will have my game in it, won't open. I can't find any similar questions or answers and I have no clue how this code is preventing the opening of the new 'maingame' tkinter window. Could someone explain to me why this code is stopping maingame from opening while offering a new more updated solution to my 'random window' problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

#this stops the random window from appearing after the
#login fails but then stops the main window from appearing

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

username1 = "player1"
password1 = "player1pass"

username2 = "player2"
password2 = "player2pass"

authorised = False
failed = False
attempts = 0

playerslogin = tk.Tk()
playerslogin.title("Authentication")
playerslogin.geometry("325x110")

labeluser1 = tk.Label(playerslogin, text="Enter the first player's username:")
labeluser1.grid(row=0)
labelpass1 = tk.Label(playerslogin, text="Enter the first player's password:")
labelpass1.grid(row=1)
labeluser2 = tk.Label(playerslogin, text="Enter the second player's username:")
labeluser2.grid(row=2)
labelpass2 = tk.Label(playerslogin, text="Enter the second player's password:")
labelpass2.grid(row=3)
authfail = tk.Label(playerslogin, text="")
authfail.grid(row=4)

while(authorised == False and failed == False):
    def checkLogin():
        user1 = e1.get()==username1
        pass1 = e2.get()==password1
        user2 = e3.get()==username2
        pass2 = e4.get()==password2

        if (user1 and user2 and pass1 and pass2):
            global authorised
            authorised = True
            playerslogin.destroy()
        else:
            global attempts, failed
            attempts = attempts + 1
            if attempts == 3:
                playerslogin.destroy()
                messagebox.showerror(title="Attempts exceeded", message="You have used all 3 attempts.")
                failed = True
            else:
                authfail.config(text = f"Login failed. Attempts left: {3-attempts}")

    e1 = tk.Entry(playerslogin)
    e2 = tk.Entry(playerslogin, show = "*")
    e3 = tk.Entry(playerslogin)
    e4 = tk.Entry(playerslogin, show = "*")
    e5 = tk.Button(playerslogin, text = "Enter", command = checkLogin)

    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e5.grid(row=4, column=1)

    playerslogin.mainloop()


#Login/authorisation code ends here, this is where the game begins

#Creating a deck and preparing the game
class Card:
  def __init__(self, colour, number):
    self.colour = colour
    self.number = number

  def getColour(self):
      return self.colour

  def getNumber(self):
      return self.number

#Cards are of colours Red, Yellow and Black, and go from 1 to 10

r1 = Card("Red", 1)
r2 = Card("Red", 2)
r3 = Card("Red", 3)
r4 = Card("Red", 4)
r5 = Card("Red", 5)
r6 = Card("Red", 6)
r7 = Card("Red", 7)
r8 = Card("Red", 8)
r9 = Card("Red", 9)
r10 = Card("Red", 10)

y1 = Card("Yellow", 1)
y2 = Card("Yellow", 2)
y3 = Card("Yellow", 3)
y4 = Card("Yellow", 4)
y5 = Card("Yellow", 5)
y6 = Card("Yellow", 6)
y7 = Card("Yellow", 7)
y8 = Card("Yellow", 8)
y9 = Card("Yellow", 9)
y10 = Card("Yellow", 10)

b1 = Card("Black", 1)
b2 = Card("Black", 2)
b3 = Card("Black", 3)
b4 = Card("Black", 4)
b5 = Card("Black", 5)
b6 = Card("Black", 6)
b7 = Card("Black", 7)
b8 = Card("Black", 8)
b9 = Card("Black", 9)
b10 = Card("Black", 10)

deck = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10]

#function to check who wins
def checkwinner(card1, card2):
    colour1 = card1.getColour()
    number1 = card1.getNumber()
    colour2 = card2.getColour()
    number2 = card2.getNumber()

    if (colour1 == colour2):
        if (number1 > number2):
            return "player1"
        else:
            return "player2"
    else:
        if (colour1 == "Red"):
            if (colour2 == "Black"):
                return "player1"
            else:
                return "player2"
        elif (colour1 == "Yellow"):
            if (colour2 == "Red"):
                return "player1"
            else:
                return "player2"
        elif (colour1 == "Black"):
            if (colour2 == "Yellow"):
                return "player1"
            else:
                return "player2"

player1deck = []
player2deck = []

#game GUI goes here

while (authorised):
    shuffleddeck = []
    shuffleddeck = deck
    random.shuffle(shuffleddeck)

    maingame = tk.Tk()
    maingame.title("Louise's Card Game")
    maingame.geometry("600x350")

    gameturns = tk.Label(maingame, text="put turns here")
    gameturns.grid(row=0, column = 0)
    
    
    maingame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. We don't need the entire program to debug a problem with an extra window.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should create exactly one instance of `Tk`. You are creating at least three, and potentially an infinite number. Each one starts as a blank window.

Comment: What do you mean by instance of tk exactly? is there a way to make one instance and have all the windows 'inside' the first instance or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `tk.Tk` is a class. When you do `tk.Tk()` you are creating an instance of that class. Each instance of `Tk` creates a new window.